# Accidentally deleted Python 3 on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: 18.04, python, session

Accidentally I deleted Python 3. Python deletion was interrupted midway in terminal when I found the icon on desktop started disappeaing one by one, then I powered off my system. I restarted my system, but now I am unable to login it says "Start of session failed" even my password is correct. I also tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> but unable to login it says "Login incorrect".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press Alt+Ctrl+F4

Type Login Id as root

Then enter password.

Now you can run

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall
```

Comment: Normally you can't login as root on Ubuntu... What you can perhaps to here is login as yourself on one of the Alt-Ctrl-F* TTYs, where you can `sudo apt...`

Answer (score 1):

if files or packages that belong to the ubuntu innards were removed try

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall
```

from bash.

if you are not on main ubuntu but kde, lxde or other flavours change the package accordingly.